# MVC JOptionPane and checkbox for don't show this message again

Tags: java, swing

What is the best way to implement JOptionPanes for error messages? I could have a total of ten error messages if I decide to take the application that far but a minimal of 5 in design. The JOptionPanes would be called in a class that extends abstract action. The JOptionPanes would only be shown if the user input fails validation. The design pattern I chose was static factories.

```
public class ApplicationErrorPanes {

    public static class NewSupplierError extends JOptionPane {
        //JOptionPane details with return.....
    }

    //More static factories.....
}
```

For the checkbox in the JOptionPanes I am going to use an Object[] as the object param of the API but what is the best way to keep track of the checkbox whether it has been checked or not in the application even when the application closes?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127908/how-to-make-a-do-not-ask-me-again-dialog-pop-up-box-with-java-solved/31128104#31128104)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes that completely answers the second question. Can you clarify some of how the properties API works for storing data is it file based using streams? Seems that way from the API. Also one last thing can you explain the param in the constructor for the API? Just interested in knowing.....Curiosity killed the cat but not the programmer.....

Comment: 1- `Properies` can read/write to any `Input/OutputStream`, so if you supply it a file stream, then it will write to a file, then example I linked does this, but leaves it open for others to decided where it should write to.  You could use the `Preferences` API which takes care of the storage for your or use what ever persistence model you want (like a database for example).  The example could use a with `Storage` extension which would allow you to configure it, but that's going way beyond the question.

Comment: 2- The `Object` message parameter is anything you want to show on the `JOptionPane`, simply tried to maintain the basic contract of the existing `JOptionPane` API.  So if you pass it a `String`, then it will simple show the text in a `JLabel`, if your pass it some kind of `Component`, it will show that within it's own panel and anything is converted to a `String` via `Object#toString` and displayed in a `JLabel`

Comment: @MadProgrammer My apologies I meant the Properties (Properties defaults) constructor.....not sure on how to use that....I wasn't specific.....What do you think about static factories for organization and grouping of the joptionpanes?

Comment: The default constructor for `Properties` doesn't do a lot, it extends from `Hashtable` and uses it's functionality to as the backing store.  Personally, I would hide the functionality of the JOptionPane and simply have some kind of "showError" which takes parameters that can used to generate the final output, this way, if you decide to do something more complicated, you can change it within the utility API, and not everywhere else in your code, but that's me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer So basically instead of extending just use a field variable for the JOptionPane and pass in the params for the pane in showError. This would put the update of the view on the constructor which I think is fine in MVC. Also all JOptionPanes would have the checkbox and would call a boolean from the controller based on the property setting. I would have to have an instance of a controller specifically for the JOptionPane business logic (Properties API). I don't think there would even be a need for a model.....

Comment: Technically, the message is the model ;).  But you also have "should show" which makes up part of the model as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer One more question and I am done....You lost me on the "should show"? I would up vote your first comment if I could but I don't have 15 rep. If I remember I will come back and do it. Thank You so much for the help. Ever need any leg work let me know I will be more than glad to assist you as you have assisted me and continue to.....

Comment: Basically, you have a message which is coming in to the API, which is what should be shown to the user, this is one model.  The API also manages the "do not show this message again" state, this is another model, so technically, you kind of have two, depending on how you look at it, but these operate at different levels within the API ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically I did exactly what MadProgrammer suggested in the above comments....

This is the model:

```
public class ErrorMessageModel {

  private Properties settings;

  private FileInputStream inputStream;

  private FileOutputStream outputStream;

  public ErrorMessageModel() {

    settings = new Properties();

  }

  public void loadProperties() {
    if (settings != null) {
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

            settings.load(inputStream);

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }

  public String getErrorMessage(String key) {
    return settings.getProperty(key);
  }

  public boolean isDisplayable(String key) {
    if (settings.getProperty(key).equals("false")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }

  public void saveProperties(String key, String value) {
    settings.put(key, value);

    storeProperties();
  }

  public void storeProperties() {
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

        settings.store(outputStream, null);

        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the view:

```
public class ErrorMessagePane {

  private JLabel message;

  private JCheckBox checkBox;

  private JPanel panel;

  public ErrorMessagePane(Container parent, String errorMessage) {

    panel = new JPanel (new MigLayout(""));

    message = new JLabel (errorMessage);
    message.setFont(ApplicationStyles.STANDARD_FONT);
    panel.add(message);

    checkBox = new JCheckBox("Don't Show This Message Again");
    checkBox.setFont(ApplicationStyles.STANDARD_FONT);
    panel.add(checkBox);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, panel, "Error",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }

  public boolean isCheckBoxSelected () {
    return checkBox.isSelected();
  }
}
```

This is an example of the controller:

```
public class NewSupplierAction extends AbstractAction {

  private CSVFileController controller;

  private Dialog dialog;

  private AddSupplierPanel panel;

  public NewSupplierAction(String name, CSVFileController controller,
        Dialog dialog, AddSupplierPanel panel) {
    super(name);
    this.panel = panel;
    this.controller = controller;
    this.dialog = dialog;
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (new ValidateSupplierID().validate(panel.getSupplierID())
            && new ValidateString().validate(panel.getSupplierName())) {
        controller.addSupplier(new Supplier(panel.getSupplierName(),
                Integer.parseInt(panel.getSupplierID())));
        dialog.getDialog().dispose();
    } else {

        ErrorMessageModel errorModel = new ErrorMessageModel ();

        errorModel.loadProperties();

        if (errorModel.isDisplayable("NewSupplierDisplay")) {
            ErrorMessagePane pane = new ErrorMessagePane (panel.getAddSupplierPanel(), errorModel.getErrorMessage("NewSupplier"));
            if (pane.isCheckBoxSelected()) {
                errorModel.saveProperties("NewSupplierDisplay", "false");
                errorModel.storeProperties();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```